# Clipping a square 70*70px to a square

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

Before I was making my `UIImage`s circular by using the code below:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Images are of 70*70px size, I want to do the same in `CGImageContext` and save the result rather than set the corner radius like above as this slows down the UI considerably. Is there anyway to do this in `CGImageContext`? Thanks

Comment: "I would like to encourage you to dive into CALayer and its properties, because most of what you can achieve with that will be faster than drawing your own things using Core Graphics" from [rendering section](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/custom-controls.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a rounded mask instead of rounding the corners which slows the performance.

Swift:

```
let roundMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
roundMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.frame.size.width/2,height: self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.frame.size.height/2)).CGPath
self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.layer.mask = roundMaskLayer
self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Objective-C:

```
CAShapeLayer *roundMaskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
roundMaskLayer.path = (__bridge CGPathRef)([UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.bounds.size.width/2, self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.bounds.size.height/2)]);
self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.layer.mask = roundMaskLayer;
self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to render and save; if masking is not performant enough then this snippet will do that.

```
+(UIImage *)roundedImage:(UIImage *)image dimension:(CGFloat)dimension {

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dimension, dimension)];
    imageview.layer.cornerRadius = dimension/2;
    imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageview.image = image;
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageview.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [imageview drawViewHierarchyInRect:imageview.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *renderedRound = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return renderedRound;

}
```

Comment: is the dimension the width of the image or the height? Have tried both and I'm getting more of an oval than a circle.

Comment: you said you wanted a square so width == height , it should be outputting a circle... actually see edit